# Issue on JSON nested Array objects into TableVIew

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode, ios9

I've tried many ways but i'm unable get the data from  `Something` Array and show it in `UITableView` based on `indexPath`.
`something` is like below response

```
    {
  "results": [
    {
      "Something": [
        [
          {
            "airV": "LX",
            "class": "Y"
          }
        ]
      ],

    },
    {
      "Something": [
        [
          {
            "airV": "FZ",
            "class": "Y"
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "airV": "FZ",
            "class": "Y"
          }
        ]
      ],

    },

  ],

}
```

Note : something array [] ->>> contains many arrays in it.Looping the `something` array i want to get `"airV": "LX","class": "Y"`
airv,class into `TableView`

Comment: Update your question with what you have attempted and explain what issues you are having.

Comment: i can get the data from single array [something] but i want to loop the  multiple [something] ]arrays and display the data in tableview with arv,class based on index

Answer (score 0):

You can store the NSArray of (something) and iterate over that array based on NSIndexPath.

```
NSArray * arrayofSomething /* Your Array */
Inside your cellForRowAtIndexPath you can get the objects from arrayofSomething based on index.

Obj *obj = [arrayofSomething objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```